# Changing div opacity excluding some of the div contents - jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, opacity

I have several .box div including short text (`<p>`) and a thumbnail. I'm trying to change opacity of text within a .box div when any part of the .box is hovered, but I don't want the image affected. So far I've got this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".box").fadeTo("fast", 0.6);

$(".box").hover(function(){
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0); 
},function(){
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.6);
});
});
```

I know it must be quite simple, but I'm stuck. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get just the `<p>` inside to apply fade to, like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
  $(".box p").fadeTo("fast", 0.6);

  $(".box").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("p").fadeTo("fast", 1.0); 
  },function(){
    $(this).find("p").fadeTo("fast", 0.6);
  });
});
```

This uses `$(".box p")` to only fade the `<p>` elements initially, then in the hover (for the entire box) we're finding the same `<p>` elements inside.  If you did `$(".box p").hover(...)` only hovering on the `<p>` itself would work.

Comment: Brilliant! That works perfectly. It's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

User `$(".box p")` selector

Comment: It's very simple and elegant, unfortunately it only works when you hover over the p area.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably place the thumbnail image outside the box you're trying to fade or use a more precise selector like $('.box p'). Depends if you want to have the box decoration itself fade, or just the text.

this might also work:

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="thumbnail" src="" style="float: left; /* or position abosolute"/>
    <div id="box">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         // $('.box p').fadeIn('fast'); 
         // or:
         $('.box').fadeIn('fast');
     });
</script>
```